# How to recover the required CNAME record for google apps?

Tags: g-suite, gmail

I just deleted all CNAME records on my domain name by mistake. Now mail.mydomainname.com point to a invalid address. Then I added a CNAME record with alias `mail` and make it point to ghs.google.com as the instruction given by google. But actually http://ghs.google.com point to an invalid address at google.

I remember I had a CNAME record named googlexxxxxxxx where xxxxxxxx is something like a authentication code. So where can I find that xxxxxxxx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to @ErikA answer. There are two DNS changes that are made with Google Apps.

1. Domain Verification, which is the
   `googleXXXXXXX.yourdomain.com` you
   mention. This is done to confirm you
   are the owner of the domain, and
   should point to `google.com`.

   ```
   EXAMPLE: googleXXXXXXX.yourdomain.com => google.com
   ```
2. Mail, and all other apps like chat,
   docs, calendar etc should have a
   CNAME, which point to
   `ghs.google.com`. It is not a
   website, therefor not responding to
   HTTP requests.

   ```
   EXAMPLE: mail => ghs.google.com
   ```

To recover the `googleXXXXXXX` address you should just have to go to the Google Apps admin as the service should have detected the dropped validation and ask you to re-validate. You can submit the re-validation here: **http://www.google.com/a/YOURDOMAIN.COM/VerifyOwnership**, placing your domain in the proper spot.

The 2nd CNAMES you can just recreate as the destination is always the `ghs.google.com` and the pointer can be whatever you like. Just make sure they match the URL settings in the Google Apps admin.

Comment: You got the point. My question is how to recover googleXXXXXXX? I login with admin but it does not detected the dropped validation and ask me to re-validate as what you said

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47283) Google's help page on what you need to do to set up a CNAME for their Google Apps platform.

Comment: I have already read that help page. My question is how to recover googleXXXXXXX?

Comment: I'd guess you probably don't need to worry about it. The validation is a one-time thing, to prove that you actually own the domain. Once that's been proven, you're home free. I've had GApps set up for my domain for many years, and that validation CNAME only existed for long enough to let them verify and then it was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://admin.google.com/<YourDomainName>/ForgotAdminAccountInfo
```

change the `<YourDomainName>` with your domain name

all the best